# Howto change text of QPushButton on long-running task, and change back when task done?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have some code like that:

```
class MyApp(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setupUi(self, *args):
        super(MyApp, self).setupUi(*args)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.doCheck)

    def doCheck(self):
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Checking...", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        # Code to do real checking here... (it's a network app)
        # When check done, display result in a "QTextBrowser" 
        # ....
        # Change text of Button to "Done!"
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Done!", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

But the result not as I expect. 
My app do network checking and display result ok, but the button did not change text to "Checking..." when the check begin; it's only change text to "Done!" when everything is finished!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing button label you should run `QApplication::processEvents()` to update UI with new label.

Notice that your UI will be freezed while long task is running. To avoid this you should sometimes call `QApplication::processEvents()` during long operation or run this operation in separate `QThread`.

Comment: It works! You're awesome. 
I also think it can be done with QThread, i tried but it quite difficult. Do you know some good documentation about it? Thank you very much! ;D

Comment: I can only advise you to read [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QThread.html).